# PHP Mail Headers

Tags: php, email, email-headers

Essentially what I'm trying to do is attach a file to an email I'm sending out. Simple enough, right? For some reason or another it does not like the following code (presumably because of the headers). Can anyone help?

**Thanks in advance!!**

```
$subject = "File ".date("Ymd");
$message = "NONE";
$filename = "test.csv";

$content = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($filename)));
$uid = md5(uniqid(time()));
$name = basename($file);

$header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$header .= "From: noreply@x.com\r\n";
$header .= "Reply-To: noreply@x.com\r\n";


$header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\r\n\r\n";
$header .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";
$header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type:text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
$header .= $message."\r\n";
$header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: text/csv; name=\"".$filename."\"\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"\r\n\r\n";
$header .= $content."\r\n\r\n";
$header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
//echo $header;

if (mail($to_email, $subject, $message, $header)) {
    echo "mail send ... OK"; 
} else {
    echo "mail send ... ERROR!";
}
```

And the error:

**Warning:** mail() [function.mail]: Bad parameters to mail() function, mail not sent.

Comment: What does `$to_email` contain?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please please please don't build your own MIME emails. Use [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com) or [Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org), which do almost everything for you. You can replace you entire script with about 5 or 6 lines of code.

And best of all, they'll give you far better error messages/diagnostics than the pathetically stupid `mail()` function ever will.

Comment: Good call. I was trying to avoid using a library but once I popped one into place it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on building your own header, I would suggest doing so with the aid of your output buffer - also I noticed that you were failing to close up your content boundaries. Pasted below is how I would edit the header generating part of your script.

```
ob_start();

?>
MIME-Version: 1.0
From: noreply@x.com
Reply-To: noreply@x.com
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="<?php echo $uid; ?>"

This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
--<?php echo $uid; ?>
Content-Type:text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<?php echo $message; ?>

--<?php echo $uid; ?>--
--<?php echo $uid; ?>
Content-Type: text/csv; name="<?php echo $filename; ?>"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="<?php echo $filename; ?>"

<?php echo $content; ?>

--<?php echo $uid; ?>--
<?php

$header = trim(ob_get_clean());
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Geekmail](http://www.geekology.co.za/blog/2009/11/simpler-way-to-send-text-html-emails-with-attachments-in-php/) PHP library makes it easy to add attachments to emails (and to send emails in general):

```
$geekMail = new geekMail();
$geekMail->setMailType('text');
$geekMail->from("noreply@x.com");
$geekMail->to($to_email);
$geekMail->subject($subject);
$geekMail->message($message);
$geekMail->attach($filename);
if (!$geekMail->send()){
  //an error occurred sending the email
  $errors = $geekMail->getDebugger();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to populate destination address (in the code sample) and you have your message both in headers (that definitely extends further than headers) and in body…